# Iterate Map in Java

Tags: java

Entry which needs to compare with the List and get the value from Map which is not there is the List.

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : itemObj.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        for (ItemProcessVO processVO : itemDetails2){
            if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(processVO.getAccount())){
                String account = processVO.getAccount();
                lstAccVO.add(account);
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the code i have used.I have Map of entry.getKey() has 6 Values while itemDetail2 has only 5 elements.I need to display only the missing account after comparing.

Comment: so do you only need to return the keys that are in the map but not in the list or do you want to still do what you above?

Comment: @OP I have added another answer, let me know if that helps

Comment: Yes Michael Ritter I need to return the keys are in the map but not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do the trick. It uses case insensitive comparison and prints remaining keys in the end, more explanation is in comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> itemObj = new HashMap<>(); //Your Map
    List<ItemProcessVO> itemDetails2 = new ArrayList<>();// Your list

    //First, get all the keys of the map
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>(itemObj.keySet());

    //Now, iterate through list and remove the matching items
    for(ItemProcessVO processVO : itemDetails2){
        String key = pop(keys, processVO.getAccount());
        //If key is not null then remove it
        if(null != key){
            keys.remove(key);
        }
    }

    //Now, iterate through remaining keys and print the values
    for(String key : keys){
        System.out.println("Missing value " + itemObj.get(key));
    }
}

private static String pop(Set<String> set, String key){
    if(null == set){
        return null;
    }else{
        for(String element : set){
            if(element.equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the Solution. But it did not work . I have changes the pop method  private static String pop(Set<String> set, String key){
   if(null == set){
          return null;
       }else{
   Iterator<String> itr = set.iterator(); 
   while(itr.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(itr.next());
      String next = itr.next();
              if(next.equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
                  return next;
              }
    }
      }
  return key;
 } . The String next = itr.next(); java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: I have made a change, try it now?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an `else`-statement to your if clause that stores that account in a local variable. Then after your for loops you can do whatever with that.

Hint: you can use loop over `Map#keySet()` instead of `Map#entrySet()` and bypass the entries that way.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided example you compared the key with the account, simply use the else- statement to find the missingAccounts to iterate after this loop over them.

```
List<ItemProcessVO> missingAccounts= new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : itemObj.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    for (ItemProcessVO processVO : itemDetails2){
        if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(processVO.getAccount())){
            String account = processVO.getAccount();
            lstAccVO.add(account);
        }else{
            missingAccounts.add(account)
        }
    }
}
```